# TCP snd_cwnd in the linux kernel

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel

What does `tcp_sock.snd_cwnd` represent in the kernel? The comments claim it is the congestion window size for the sender. But its values hover around the 10-30 range. Is it measured in MSS?